# Proving that □A → A is valid iff R is reflexive?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

How to prove, in modal logic, that \square $A\to  A$ is valid iff $R$ is reflexive? (shouldn't this be the definition of $T$ axiom in modal logic)?

(NOTE: The question was edited because I made a mistake by misplacing the necessity sign. Former formulation does not make sense at all)

Comment: The formula defines the pathetic relations, i.e. those relations $R$ with $xRy$ iff $x = y$

Comment: You've already asked the updated question in this [post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/86585/how-to-prove-in-modal-logic-that-a%e2%86%92a-is-valid-t-axiom-iff-r-is-reflexive) and fully accepted an answer without any further question and comment there, so what do you still doubt?

Answer (score 3):

$T$ axiom is not defined as such, instead it's [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic) in most modal logics the othere way around as below:

> T, Reflexivity Axiom: □p → p (If p is necessary, then p is the case.)

> T holds in most but not all modal logics. Zeman (1973) describes a few exceptions, such as $S1^0$.

$A \to \square A$ is an [inference rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_modal_logic) (not an axiom) in the weakest normal modal logic $K$ only when $A$ is a theorem:

> Necessitation rule: $\vdash A$ implies $\vdash \square A$.

Obviously in general if A is a mere contingent proposition, we cannot assert A must be necessarily true in our world even if our world is reflexive normal modal system $T$ accessible to itself.